# How to Fix the "No active batch" Error for Search API

Tags: api, search, solr, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I try integration solr search on tomcat for my project but have some problems like :

I use [search api](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api) and [solr search](https://www.drupal.org/project/search_api_solr) and when i try index nodes i have error  :

> No active batch.

How i can fix it(solr connection work)?

Comment: Do you use https://www.drupal.org/project/securepages ?

Comment: I found my erros? i use https conections

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first you need to check if solr search service (tomcat) is on, and running

url to check -> http://localhost:8983/solr, 
(right path you can find in tomacat/solr config files)
on some servers link might be like this http://localhost:8080/solr/

if ok, go to 
admin/config/search/apachesolr/settings/solr/edit

and enter a working link to solr server field, thats all

next go to admin/config/search/apachesolr

there will be button "Index all queued content"

also on Search settings page
admin/config/search/settings

you need to set use solr as default search module

Comment: All works it's was error with https!! thanks for response